# vscode remote-ssg : server status check failed - waiting and retrying

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server

This case that i can't connect to the remote because of "server status check failed - waiting and retrying" have happened several times.
However, when i delete the directory "data" and the file which has the suffix with '.log','.pid' or '.token'  in remote server under the direcotory ".vscode-server" , this problem should be solved.[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwEwf.png

Answer (score 1):

on your remote server side, check vscode-server daemon process is not quit from last connect, kill them all and retry

```
$ ps aux | grep vscode-server
$ kill -2 pid
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried rebooting the remote machine and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Both of [jackytse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10136713/jackytse)'s and [Hao Tan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3374402/hao-tan)'s answers are correct. The whole problem was that there was a hanging process of VS Code that was not terminated correctly, due to any reason; in my case it was misuse of `ps` command.

Killing all processes with `vscode-server` in them will fix the problem, and thus, rebooting the machine too because it essentially kills all the processes.

You can kill all `vscode-server` processes using the following

```
$ ps aux | grep vscode-server | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} kill -2 {}
```